# How to manage the layout folders for different resolutions and different dpi?

Tags: android, xml, view

I have doubt that how we are going to create the different layouts to support all android mobile devices. As we know that we will be creating different layouts *(mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi..)* in res folder.
What is my question is eg: I am having two mobiles say *moto e(253dpi) and samsung galaxy e7(267dpi)* where both are xhpdi. Now I will be creating xhdpi for them. But here the two screen resolutions differs (moto e(540x960) and e7(720x1280) respectively).

Now if I give some hard coded values in xhpdi xml. Whether my layout remains same for both devices? Without any alignment issues?

Comment: Refer to this document: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Don't give hard coded value to them, use different folders for them

Comment: @DerGolem..Thanks for your suggestion,but  I have gone through that link already.so i got this doubt.

Comment: @Dorami..I have gone through few links they said to use relative layout,where in some cases i will be setting a view  android:layout_marginTop="80dp"..so what happen in this case?

Answer (score 1):

**Use following folders if you wish to have tablet-specific layouts:**

```
layout-large-mdpi   (1024x600)
layout-large-xhdpi  (1200x1920)
layout-xlarge-mdpi  (1280x800)
layout-xlarge-xhdpi (2560x1600)
```

For Mobiles:

```
res/drawable        (default)
res/drawable-ldpi  (240x320)
res/drawable-mdpi  (320x480)
res/drawable-hdpi  (480x800)
res/drawable-xhdpi  (720x1280)
res/drawable-xxhdpi (1080x1920)
res/drawable-xxxhdpi (1440X2560)
```

Dinems for mobiles:

```
res/values/dimens.xml(default)
res/values-ldpi/dimens.xml   (240x320)
res/values-mdpi/dimens.xml   (320x480)
res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml   (480x800)
res/values-xhdpi/dimens.xml  (720x1280)
res/values-xxhdpi/dimens.xml (1080x1920)
```

Comment: dimens.xml will help?

Comment: ya they will help you, but you have to put dimen's value according to your needs