# Supporting different devices with different layout

Tags: android, android-layout, androiddesignsupport

I have doubt in making the layout for other deices I mean to support different devices of different resolutions. I have made an application and it is working well on hdpi devices and I tested on Samsung Galaxy grand which has 320dp-460dp and 480px-800px.

May application is looking awesome on this device. but when I run on other devices its gone bad. SO I am suggested to make the folder like layout-large, layout-xlarge and layout-xxlarge but there is a lot of difference in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763322/android-supporting-multiple-resolution-with-multiple-layout-folder) link and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31242604/how-to-manage-the-layout-folders-for-different-resolutions-and-different-dpi) link

So this makes me confuse , with which name I have to make the layout folders to support all devices ?? please tell me

and also tell me I have some hard coded values in my layout such as left margin 13 dp to make my design look perfect on hdpi device should I make it more in other xhdpi devices ???

and also which devices comes in layout-large folder and so on  please answer my both confusion , thanks in advance

Comment: Making a specific layout folder to support a certain size does not mean your app won't run on other sizes. It just means your app would work better on this specific size.

Comment: Read the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: support multiple screens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380885/android-support-multiple-screens)

Comment: I know it would work , but I wanted to know with which name I have to make the folders ?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I have read this link already, but wanted to know which devices fall in particular folders

Comment: Why do you worry WHICH device falls in a category? Just provide the resources scaled for the correct density folders and it's ALL DONE. Automatically. Well, you might have to adjust some dimensions, and always use **dp**s and **sp**s. But basically, you're already fine.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein so its mean I have to only make changes in dpis and spis I have given in the layout

Comment: it's **dp**s and **sp**s. In your different `dimens.xml` files (you're providing several `values` folders to contain each different one - following the same naming rules used for the `drawable` folders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Google's code as an example of how to do stuff. The docs on "Supporting multiple screen" is a bit old and outdated. The best way to keep up with the current conventions is to follow other's codes.

[Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git/+/android-5.1.0_r3/res/) is the source code for the Calendar app. Yes, there a lot of different folders for layouts/drawable/values but you have to consider the fact that there are a lot of devices with varying sizes and pixel densities.

Also, why do you want to make many folders for layout? You make a few layouts and let the values and drawables do the rest of the work. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: so you saying that I just have to make the single layout files and then gives margins in the dimens folder ? is it ?

Comment: Yes, that's basically it.

Comment: can you please give me which name should I use for the which dimension and resoultin of devices ,

Comment: like some one said to made layout-small and layout-large in layout folder so what should i make for the dimension folder and how many I have to make if I want to support all devices

Comment: Please check this out:  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git/+/android-5.1.0_r3/res/

Comment: I am not getting what are you trying to say in this link ? @Rafiduzzaman

Comment: This is the res directory for the official Calendar app by Google. I want you to notice the names of the values/drawables/layouts folders used in this project.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are interested in knowing which device falls under which folder, then check this figure from the [Official Android Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

[image: Illustration of how Android roughly maps actual sizes and densities to generalized sizes and densities (figures are not exact).]

Of course **you need to know** the actual size or density of the physical device

Comment: so tell me how ? "Of course you need to know the actual size or density of the physical device"